# Why couldn't Graham hear his children?

Tags: signs

Why couldn't Graham hear his children?

In the beginning of the movie, Graham and Caroline, the sheriff, were investigating the crop circle. While Graham and her were investigating it, Graham says, "I can't hear my children." Was being in the circle having some sort of effect on him and Caroline?

Why was that?

Comment: Its been awhile since I have seen it, but Possibly because the children had moved far enough away from Graham and he did not know where they currently were. I don't think cause there was some sound deadening effect from the circle.

Comment: Pretty sure this might take place very early in the film when they discover the CC in his field, and he reports it to the sheriff thinking its the neighbor harassing him again.

Comment: I say that because usually people who visit crop circles have these weird effects happening to them.

Comment: It maybe a stupid question because obviously they were mourning Whodini's death. HOWEVER, it seemed rather mysterious given the circumstances and history of crop circles were a major influence on the movie, with an obvious sci-fi alien invasion plot to it

Comment: I know. It's like a few minutes after they discover the crop circle.

Answer (score 1):

As a father... when you "dont hear your children", you know that something is up. There is always the innate sense and recognition of sound that your children are making in the other room, as to provide a watchful sense of security.

So while talking with the sheriff in the field, the father stands up (already in a tense and confusing situation), and realizes he hasn't heard his children playing, talking or making other noises. He says "I dont hear my children" not because of some mysterious power the crop circles were making, rather to tell us (the viewer) that he is a protective and responsible father (a character trait that comes up often in this movie) who didn't hear his children and knew something was awry.

Comment: Well then, *why* didn't he hear his children?

Comment: are you asking "why" as in "why were the kids silent?" because the kids were "up to something". in this case they dealt with the family dog that was growling and attacking Beau the daughter. in shock they didn't know what to do afterwards. they just killed a pet. do they hide?  do they run and tell dad?

Comment: I (and actually, the OP) are asking "why" as in "why was there no acoustic transmission of signals from the kids to their father happening?" I think your answer described the out-of-universe aspect of why this was highlighted, but the question sounds (to me, anyways) as if it focused on the in-universe view, to which "Because the kids were not emitting any such signals, following sudden and unexpected event XYZ" is an absolutely valid answer.

Comment: i gave the in-universe answer. the director used a common parental trope in the film to move the plot from the field to the farmhouse. there is no weird unexplainable force with the crop circles as to why no "acoustic transmission" was being received. its explained by regular real-world phenomenon. the conversation turned toward the dog. father knew the kids were playing with the dogs. father realized he couldn't hear his kids playing, and knew something was awry.

Comment: "to move the plot from the field to the farmhouse" - as how the plot moves is a behind-the-scenes decision of the director and/or screenwriter, rather than anything the characters would take into account, that sounds about as "out-of-universe" to me as can be ;) But never mind, the fact that the kids are indeed being silent, as you also explained, completely answers the question IMHO.

Comment: It just seemed to be like that because many of the aspects of crop circles historically have had weird effects with being in them.